Will the real Shas Kattan please stand up
There is an old tradition commonly referenced in the yeshiva community that Masekhet Ketubot is the "Shas Kattan" of Talmud Bavli, that is, it contains ideas that connect to just about every other area of Shas (short for "Shisha Sidrei," all six orders of the Mishnah). The source and force of this idea is the subject of this question on Mi Yodeya.
Personally, I have thought that this doesn't really seem to be the case; although Ketubot does indeed have a lot of cases involving civil law and connects to many topics covered in tractates Bava Metzia, Bava Batra, and Shevu'ot, and one encounters the laws of Shabbat and Yom Tov in the first 10 pages, it doesn't contain much from Zera'im, Kodshim or Taharot (or Mo'ed really). There seem to me to be much better candidates for Shas Kattan, such as Pesachim or Nedarim, when one considers all six orders of the Mishnah.
My question is - and one that is worth a bounty of lots of extra points from me - would there be a way to computationally determine which tractate has the most varied connections to other tractates in Shas?
There are a few (valid) ways one might interpret this question, which could produce different results, but I'm happy to reward any good attempt with lots of bounty points. See below for some possible approaches. Additionally/alternatively, can you make (or reference) a visualization showing the Talmud's interconnectivity with something like a chord diagram? Or a similar kind of visualization that can help display what the "real Shas Kattan" would look like? (Sefaria has some nice visualizations here, but none that answer my specific question about the Talmud Bavli).
Computationally speaking, which tractate of Talmud Bavli is the real "Shas Kattan"?

Possible Approaches
Page-by-page Seder Score: give each page of talmud a score between 0-6 for its "order connectivity breadth," defined by the number of orders (out of the 6 orders, or sedarim of the Mishnah) cross-referenced by a single page, and then find the Tractate with the highest score averaged across its pages.
Simple Point-Per-Tractate Score: for each tractate, give one point for every other unique tractate (in Mishnah, Talmud, or Tosefta) referenced, with the possible highest score of 63. Perhaps it would be "more fair" to divide that score by the number of words in the given tractate.
Exponential Discounting of Repeated Tractate References: what I believe would be the most accurate reflection of 'shas-kattan-ness' would be to score each tractate's references as follows: give one point for every unique Tractate referenced. For the second time that tractate is referenced, give 0.5 points, then the third time, give 0.25, etc. (So, for example, if a tractate quotes Berakhot once and Shabbat thrice, it will have a score of 1 + 1.75 = 2.75). Again, perhaps divide the final score by number of words in the tractate for fairness

Of course you're looking at "actual Shas" kattan ... not "the much smaller piece of Shas that yeshivas typically cover, to the exclusion of all else" kattan ...

@Shalom but that's the thing, people call it "Shas kattan," not "fifty-yeshivihe-blatt-kattan". But it's also not just a new yeshivish thing; this term has a long pedigree, see this article by Tuvia Preschel

What about connections that rishonim make based on the discussion on the daf?

@Yehuda I actually started working on that also; I've made lists for "how often does Rashba quote each masechta," including in the commentary on that daf (meaning, include references to Kesubos daf 10 even if he's commenting on Kesubos daf 10), and I did the same for Ketzos + Nesivos, etc... it gets unwieldly pretty fast, but if you're curious, I haven't found any of these seforim where Kesubos is the winning number of citations. If I limited it to "first 30 daf" for each masekhta, the first 30 daf of Kesubos might win

This question has inspired an article over at the Seforim blog, most of which is reproduced below.

Using Sefaria's list of links, we can do either a simple count of how many other tractates of Shas are quoted by each tractate. In this case, a 'citation' counts whether it is a reference to the Mishnah, Tosefta, Talmud Yerushalmi, or Talmud Bavli to any one of the 63 tractates in Shas. According to this table, there is only a single tractate which manages to reference all the others: Chullin! This table also shows the results of a slightly more complex scoring method suggested in the question, where each additional citation garners incrementally smaller points in a geometric series.



Tractate
Unique Tractates Referenced
Exponential-Decrease-Score




Chullin
62
116.89577852011915


Eruvin
58
104.11961320040427


Menachot
58
104.1098582111299


Berakhot
56
101.77476863324046


Gittin
55
99.0613626539598


Bekhorot
55
95.35521305304428


Avodah Zarah
55
93.15401339507207


Bava Metzia
54
96.7636258301427


Pesachim
53
98.12823985467958


Niddah
52
91.59834762607352


Shabbat
51
93.73074903174845


Bava Batra
51
93.48292022838086


Bava Kamma
51
91.50913565878997


Chagigah
51
87.70597839355469


Kiddushin
50
90.7797232517002


Ketubot
48
86.27256274083626


Sukkah
47
84.69956454820817


Beitzah
47
79.6522365808487


Megillah
45
77.95748043013737


Arakhin
45
76.91127727914136


Sotah
45
76.47444889880535


Sanhedrin
44
83.24673657807102


Nazir
44
78.29042801260948


Makkot
44
75.13363409041631


Keritot
44
71.53747296286747


Nedarim
43
75.31631442904472


Shevuot
41
72.194636791005


Temurah
41
70.44600623844599


Rosh Hashanah
40
68.44915628246963


Moed Katan
37
63.7000732421875


Horayot
37
56.52581787109375


Yoma
36
71.1487001739068


Zevachim
36
70.46337077020688


Yevamot
36
69.9527091364871


Meilah
35
54.75389099120366


Taanit
33
57.51600646972656


Tamid
20
26.12499237060547




There is another possible way of interpreting "shas kattan"-ness, which would refer to how well balanced all of the citations are in terms of being a more fair representation of all of Shas. Although I don't think anyone had this in mind when referring to Kesubos as "Shas Kattan," it nevertheless seems like an interesting to me. In case this is interesting to anyone else, I'll show the results of my data here, but once again Chullin appears to be the winner (except maybe Bekhorot; both of them have very similar calculated deviations from an expected set of values of 1/6 citations to each Seder).

For a colorblind-friendly version, click here.

Another legitimate approach would be to understand the term "shas kattan" as a non-literal reference to "all the topics in the Torah," and ask the question: which tractate of Talmud Bavli covers the most unique topics? This question is much more difficult to answer simply because there were no tools which identified "topics" as they appear in the Talmud in the same way that people have been identifying talmudic cross-references since R. Nissim Gaon in the 11th century.
But today, we have Sefaria! Included in the Sefaira database and API docs is a way to identify which topics come up in any source, even though these tags are far from perfect. Here's a chart of all the tractates ordered by most topics identified according to Sefaria's topic links (along with the "Unique Tractates Referenced" number in the third column, as explained above)



Tractate
Topics Count
Unique Tractates Referenced




Shabbat
1133
51


Sanhedrin
1038
44


Berakhot
954
56


Pesachim
864
53


Bava Batra
781
51


Sotah
708
45


Bava Metzia
680
54


Ketubot
678
48


Eruvin
662
59


Yevamot
634
36


Kiddushin
630
50


Chullin
623
63


Gittin
616
55


Bava Kamma
611
51


Yoma
592
36


Avodah Zarah
577
55


Nedarim
541
43


Megillah
537
45


Taanit
488
33


Menachot
462
59


Chagigah
394
51


Rosh Hashanah
393
40


Niddah
384
52


Sukkah
351
47


Zevachim
313
36


Bekhorot
310
56


Moed Katan
293
37


Arakhin
289
45


Makkot
272
44


Nazir
251
44


Shevuot
242
41


Beitzah
217
47


Keritot
193
44


Horayot
183
37


Temurah
177
41


Meilah
104
35


Tamid
101
20




Here's a jupyter notebook with the code and figures, for anyone interested.

Thanks! I hope you or someone continues this, and makes a blog. So, does Tamid not quote Taharot at all, or is the graph too small there? That seems to be the only gemara that is missing a single reference to a whole seder? Is Niddah that much better than Chullin here for fractional link count - is it by eye you are saying that or did you calculate and compare scores? I recently saw this video about analyzing the connectedness of wikipedia, using math to work out "communities" based on connections etc: https://youtu.be/JheGL6uSF-4. Would love if someone would do the same here, if useful

If you remove self-referencing, what does the fractional link count chart look like?

No, but I just assumed it contained self references because Berachot has a lot of Zeraim references?

Sefaria's connections are added by mesorat hashas, algorithmacally, and by random people. their topic pages are generally taken from somewhere specific such as https://aspaklaria.info/

Just edit the answer, deleting is not necessary and would be not on keeping with the code of conduct. Also don't remove too much, answers that are just links to, or rely heavily on external sites are also frowned on. Looking forward to the blog

@RabbiKaii published finally, here, message me if you think of other similar projects to work on (I'm currently working on mapping out how often each tanna + amora quote each other)
